# HTML Table Centering

Tags: html

I am having trouble centering my table in html as I am trying to create a web page for a class.
This is what I have entered into html:

```
<table align="center" width="50%">
<tr>
<td><b>Resume:</b></td>
<td><a href="UMD Resume, general revised.docx">Click here to download my resume.</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>LinkedIn:</b></td>
<td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michellefeyder">Click here to open my LinkedIn profile.</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

However, whenever I try to add 'align' and 'width' in the  attribute, it only affects my width. It doesn't center the table.
Does anyone know of a way to both center the table in the page while applying width?

Thank you. I can provide the markup of my html page if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<table style="margin:0px auto; width:500px">
```

However align is obsolete so you may try this:

```
table {
  width:500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

ie, give width to your table and set margin auto horizontal

Comment: when he will change the width it will not be centered any more

Comment: @ZeRubeus: Indeed. Updated that :)

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your table

```
table {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bw0zm3u/)**

Answer (score 0):

try to put it inside

```
 <p align="center">

<table align="center" width="50%">
<tr>
<td><b>Resume:</b></td>
<td><a href="UMD Resume, general revised.docx">Click here to download my resume.</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>LinkedIn:</b></td>
<td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michellefeyder">Click here to open my LinkedIn profile.</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your table in a wrapping div:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Resume:</b></td>
      <td><a href="UMD Resume, general revised.docx">Click here to download my resume.</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>LinkedIn:</b></td>
      <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michellefeyder">Click here to open my LinkedIn profile.</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

 </div>
```

And then in your css file (if you want to centre the text too):

```
table {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't center an element without defining the width of its outside container. Let me show you a better way to set it up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #outside-container {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #form-container {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outside-container">
    <div id="form-container">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Resume:</b></td>
                <td><a href="UMD Resume, general revised.docx">Click here to           download my resume.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>LinkedIn:</b></td>
                <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michellefeyder">Click here to open my LinkedIn profile.</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div> <!-- CLOSE #form-container -->
</div>  <!-- CLOSE #outside-container -->
</body>
</html>
```